# How to resize an image before upload in JSF / PrimeFaces?

Tags: javascript, image, primefaces, html5-canvas, jsf-2.2

I'm trying to resize an image based off an  in JSF and somehow get it to my uploadedFileHandler.
I couldn't find an easy PrimeFaces / JSF way to do this, so I am trying this utility here: [rossturner/HTML5-ImageUploader](https://github.com/rossturner/HTML5-ImageUploader)
I don't know how to make sure that the inputFile is going to be replaced with the Javascript part.

```
<h:form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="ImageUploader.js" />
    <h:inputFile id="fileInputElement" />
</h:form>

<h:outputScript type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var uploader = new ImageUploader({
        inputElement : $("#upload\\:photo_upload\\:form\\:fileInputElement")[0],
        uploadUrl : 'i/dont/know/what/to/put/here'
        });
});
</h:outputScript>
```

This seems like it should be easy in JSF or PrimeFaces, but my search so far has failed to find a solution for the JSF world.

Basically we just want to allow mobile users to be able to take a photo and make sure that it will be resized appropriately in order to save bandwidth.
We are using JSF 2.2.15, PrimeFaces 6.1, TomCat 9.0, and Java 1.8_141.
Thanks for any tips you can provide!

Comment: MyFaces Tomahawk doesn't suit your needs?

http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/tagdoc/t_inputFileUpload.html

Comment: The tag t:inputFileUpload is what you need. I don't know if PrimeFaces have something like this.